# How to permanently change a specific bash shell color?

Tags: command-line, bash, colors

The command below is the output of the command `sudo service ssh status`

[image]

You can see that this greenish yellow font color is very hard to read, yet it is only applied to very specific cases. How can i change the various shell / bash colors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a terminal window, which terminal emulator (gnome-terminal or another one)? Would it work to change the background colour (for example to black)?

Comment: To do it independent of the terminal (of remote login) I would try with ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: The terminal emulator decides what colour to show given some specific control code, not bash. You should change the palette of your terminal emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather general method is to use **ANSI escape sequences**. It should work in text screens as well as most linux terminal window emulators.

See this link for details,

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Example 1: White text on black background

```
echo -e "\0033[37;40m###############\0033[0m"
```

Example 2: Black text on greyish white background

```
echo -e "\0033[30;47m###############\0033[0m"
```

Example 3: Using the variables `inversvid`, `greenback` and `resetvid`

```
inversvid="\0033[7m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"
greenback="\0033[1;37;42m"
echo -e "$inversvid Now it is inverse colours $resetvid"
echo -e "$greenback Now it is greenback colours $resetvid"
```

---

**Variables**, that I use in bash shellscripts, and that you might find useful:

You can create modified variable to perform what you want, for example to get a background colour where all text is visible.

```
inversvid="\0033[7m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"
redback="\0033[1;37;41m"
greenback="\0033[1;37;42m"
blueback="\0033[1;37;44m"
```

---

If you use **gnome-terminal**, which is part of standard Ubuntu desktop, you can use the dropdown menu

**'Edit -- Settings' and the tab 'Colors'**

to modify the colours until all text is easy to read.

Most terminal emulators have similar menus. `xterm` has command line options for this purpose.